# PIG HBASE FAILED ; store CSV

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I'm beginning with the environment Hadoop, HBase, Pig;
I would storer a database on a Hbase table;
here are my requeste:

hbase->
create
to create my database.

I rebooted my CVS file on HDFS file
hadoop dfs-copyFromLocal ~ /data.csv / user / hduser / location.csv

I executed my requeste PIG

raw_data = LOAD '/ user / hduser / data.csv' USING PigStorage (';') AS (
WMO: int,
maturity: charArray,
temperature: int,
temps_present: int,
direction_du_vent: int,
force_du_vent: int,
pressure: int);

STORE INTO raw_data 'hbase :/ / TrafficFlowGrenoble' USING
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage (
WMO: int maturity: charArray temperature: int temps_present: direction_du_vent int int force_du_vent int pressure: int ');

HERE IS MY ERRORS:
2013-07-22 22:30:31,870 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map REDUCE job (s) failed!
2013-07-22 22:30:31,872 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion PigVersion UserId StartedAt FinishedAt Features
1.1.2 0.11.1 hduser 2013-07-22 22:28:45 2013-07-22 22:30:31 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId Alias ​​Feature Message Outputs
job_201307222219_0001 raw_data MAP_ONLY Message: Job failed! Error - Failure JobCleanup Task, Task: task_201307222219_0001_m_000001 hbase :/ / TrafficFlowGrenoble,

Input (s):
Failed to read data from "/ user / hduser / data.csv"

Output (s):
Failed to Produce result in "hbase :/ / TrafficFlowGrenoble"

counters:
Total records written: 0
Total bytes written: 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count: 0
Total bags Proactively spilled: 0
Proactively spilled Total records: 0

vERSION : 
hadoop-1.1.2
pig-0.11.1

## export HBASE_HOME=/usr/lib/hbase

#export PIG_CLASSPATH=”`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`:$PIG_CLASSPATH”
   export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=”`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH”
   #export PIG_CLASSPATH="$PIG_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.8.jar"
   export PIG_CLASSPATH="/usr/local/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml:/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.8.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/$
   #export PIG_CLASSPATH=/home/nadir/Documents/pig-0.11.1.jar

Comment: You should look for stack trace. You can find it from jobtracker http interface. It gives you a link while running like: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201309270759_0003 Update the question with that stack trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code above is exactly what you did than your input file is "/ user / hduser / **location**.csv" not data.csv so Pig can't find it

Comment: I was wrong about writing, I wanted to write
dfs-copyFromLocal ~ / data.csv / user / hduser / data.csv

it always gives the same ERRORS.

Comment: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.8.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase/lib/$  now It's work !!